# Reset javascript countdown at midnight

Tags: javascript, countdown

i have a page with a countdown and I want to reset the countdown at every midnight. I want to reset every midnight and start from 23 hours 59 minutes 59 second, day by da.y Could you help me? Here is the html, css and javascript. Now it is fixed manually to a date but that's not good for me. Is that possible?

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="clock">
        <div class="column days">
            <div class="timer" id="days"></div>
            <div class="text">DAYS</div>
        </div>
        <div class="timer days">:</div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="timer" id="hours"></div>
            <div class="text">ORE</div>
        </div>
        <div class="timer">:</div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="timer" id="minutes"></div>
            <div class="text">MINUTE</div>
        </div>
        <div class="timer">:</div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="timer" id="seconds"></div>
            <div class="text">SECUNDE</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


 * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #3498DB;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Microsoft YaHei";
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 320px;
    color: #fff;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.timer {
    font-family: "Segment7Standard";
    font-size: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.clock {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.clock .column {
    display: inline-block;
}
p {
    line-height: 27px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 31px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #a3deff;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
a {
    color: #a3deff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.days {
    display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
    .timer {
        font-size: 35px;
    }
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.clear-loading {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.spinner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.spinner > span,
.spinner > span:before,
.spinner > span:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.spinner > span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    -webkit-animation: effect-2 2s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: effect-2 2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: effect-2 2s infinite linear;
    animation: effect-2 2s infinite linear;
}
.spinner > span:before {
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    border-right-color: transparent;
}
.spinner > span:after {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
@-webkit-keyframes effect-2 {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes effect-2 {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

    $(function(){
    function timer(settings){
        var config = {
            endDate: '2018-05-19 09:00',
            timeZone: 'Europe/Dublin',
            hours: $('#hours'),
            minutes: $('#minutes'),
            seconds: $('#seconds'),
            newSubMessage: 'and should be back online in a few minutes...'
        };
        function prependZero(number){
            return number < 10 ? '0' + number : number;
        }
        $.extend(true, config, settings || {});
        var currentTime = moment();
        var endDate = moment.tz(config.endDate, config.timeZone);
        var diffTime = endDate.valueOf() - currentTime.valueOf();
        var duration = moment.duration(diffTime, 'milliseconds');
        var days = duration.days();
        var interval = 1000;
        var subMessage = $('.sub-message');
        var clock = $('.clock');
        if(diffTime < 0){
            endEvent(subMessage, config.newSubMessage, clock);
            return;
        }
        if(days > 0){
            $('#days').text(prependZero(days));
            $('.days').css('display', 'inline-block');
        }
        var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
            duration = moment.duration(duration - interval, 'milliseconds');
            var hours = duration.hours(),
                minutes = duration.minutes(),
                seconds = duration.seconds();
            days = duration.days();
            if(hours  <= 0 && minutes <= 0 && seconds  <= 0 && days <= 0){
                clearInterval(intervalID);
                endEvent(subMessage, config.newSubMessage, clock);
                window.location.reload();
            }
            if(days === 0){
                $('.days').hide();
            }
            $('#days').text(prependZero(days));
            config.hours.text(prependZero(hours));
            config.minutes.text(prependZero(minutes));
            config.seconds.text(prependZero(seconds));
        }, interval);
    }
    function endEvent($el, newText, hideEl){
        $el.text(newText);
        hideEl.hide();
    }
    timer();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zd82dav7/

Comment: Remove all the css, and big parts of the html. We dont care if it looks good

Answer (score 0):

Edited your fiddle here [https://jsfiddle.net/zd82dav7/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/zd82dav7/2/)

Added a new date object and used it for the end date:

`endDate:  dT.getFullYear() + "-" +  prependZero(dT.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + prependZero(dT.getDate()) + ' 23:59',`

Now it uses the current date and sets the end time to 23:59 of the current day. Meaning it will start a new counter 23 hrs 59 minutes when the clock passes midnight. Not sure if the end time supports seconds... didn't check that. But you can always just add it to the string.